# What should we do for the tag [meta-reputation]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Today, I found a tag called [meta-reputation](/questions/tagged/meta-reputation). This tag doesn’t contain tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt and is only used by 2 questions only.

These 2 questions are all about the reputation for meta stack exchange (aka MSE) and meta site that every Stack Exchange site has.

I don’t think and find any differences between the tag [meta-reputation](/questions/tagged/meta-reputation) and the tag [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation).

**UPDATE:**
I agree with @Journeyman Geek suggestion.

As @Journeyman Geek suggest, we should clarify this tag over than we merge this tag to [meta-reputation](/questions/tagged/meta-reputation). Now, what should we write for tag wiki and the tag wiki excerpt? Another choice is rename the tag, what should the tag name be? Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2:**

Maybe we rename the tag to [per-site-meta-reputation](/questions/tagged/per-site-meta-reputation).

But what should we write for “tag wiki excerpt”?

It’s bad if we write “For question related to per-site meta reputation” as an excerpt should describe why and when a tag should be used.

And what should we write for “tag wiki”?

I think we should clarify it properly so no one will be misunderstanding the tag.

Answer (score 9):

Per site metas do actually have their own 'secret' reputation system, and people *do* get confused when they get badges for things like repcapping on a per site meta. There's a handful of badges that can be triggered that way, and while both questions for the tag are closed as dupes, it is its own unique thing.

I do feel like clarifying this is for per site metas makes sense, either by renaming the tag and/or filling up the tag wiki and excerpt over merging it to the reputation tag.